# Can't forward parameters to nested macros

Tags: macros, rust

I am working on Rust macros to generate a static array of structures that describe FFI callbacks.  What I currently have is...

```
// some trivial callback functions
extern "C" fn my_fun_1(argc: u32, argv: *const i32) -> i32 { 1 }
extern "C" fn my_fun_2(argc: u32, argv: *const i32) -> i32 { 2 }


// create static array of ErlNifFunc describing above callbacks
nif_init!(b"my_module\0", 
    nif!(b"my_fun_1\0", 3, my_fun_1),
    nif!(b"my_fun_2\0", 5, my_fun_2));
```

(whole thing is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cd6f9ee69392277ad03c&version=stable))

This works because I only need to provide one expansion of the information provided to the `nif!` macro.  But now, in addition to generating an array of structs, I want to work towards generating wrapper functions for the provided functions.  So, I can't invoke `nif!` right away because I now need to do more than one expansion pass on the underlying parameters.  I effectively need to move the `nif!` invocations inside `nif_init!`, and this is where I drown.  I think the top level `nif_init!` needs to look like this...

```
nif_init!(b"my_module\0", 
    (b"my_fun_1\0", 3, my_fun_1),
    (b"my_fun_2\0", 5, my_fun_2));
```

... with the inner parenthesised parameters getting passed on to sub-macros, but I just cannot make it go.  The full non-working thing is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=72b0f16ac7b04d2d0dbc&version=stable).  To clarify, this version just tries to do the macro invocation internally.  I'm not trying to generate any wrapper functions yet.

Comment: The "fixed" version of the non-working program mentioned above is http://is.gd/nSw4vY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this case, you can't use parentheses as grouping, you need to use them as part of your macro pattern. I'd avoid using parens to avoid this confusion.

Here, I changed your macro a bit to accept zero-or-more sets of `{}`. You can macro-iterate over each of them and call your inner macro:

```
macro_rules! nif_inner {
    ($name:expr, $args:expr, $meth:expr) => ()
}

macro_rules! nif_init {
    ($module:expr, $({ $name:expr, $args:expr, $meth:expr }),*) => (
        $(nif_inner!(name, $args, $meth);)*
    )
}

nif_init!(
    "hello",
    { "name1", 1, true },
    { "name2", 2, false }
);

fn main() {}
```

Comment: Your use of brace matching illustrated how I needed to fix my original broken version.  The example you've provided couples the parameters of nif_inner to nif_init.  This is avoidable by moving the brace matching to nif_inner and using a token tree matcher in nif_init.  Parenthesis do work, but I agree that braces are less confusing.  See http://is.gd/6fZ9q7 for the decoupled version of your example.  And thanks for pulling me out of the muck once again!

Comment: @goertzenator I'm glad my example helped! I was a bit worried that I'd misread your original question and was answering the wrong thing!